# What does "next" do inside of .subscribe()?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I have seen three ways to "listen" for changes to a value via an observable / call APIs to fetch data from the backend.

One of these ways has "next:" :

```
this.MySubscription = this.myService.getStuff().subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
        <insert code to perform operations with "data">
    }, error: (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        // <insert code for what to do on failure>
    }
});
```

And on the Angular site https://angular.io/guide/observables I see this, with "next(" :

```
// Call subscribe() to start listening for updates.
const locationsSubscription = locations.subscribe({
    next(position) {
        console.log('Current Position: ', position);
    },
    error(msg) {
        console.log('Error Getting Location: ', msg);
    }
});
```

But I have been just doing it the "normal way", like this (with no "next"):

```
this.MySubscription = this.myService.getStuff().subscribe((data: any) => {
    <insert code to perform operations with "data">
}, error => {
    console.error(error);
    <insert code for what to do on failure>
});
```

Is there any functional difference between these three methods of subscribing? How does each method produce different results?

Answer (score 8):

The 3 ways you show in your question do the same thing.
It is just 3 different ways to give an observer.

- In the first one, you give a `PartialObserver<T>` object with a `next` function, which will be executed when receiving a value that is not an error
- In the second one, you give a `PartialObserver<T>` object with a `next` function, again, but with the shorthand function syntax
- In the third one, you use `Observable.subscribe(<closure>)` which is basically a shortcut to `Observable.subscribe({ next: <closure> })`

You always use the 3rd way, unless you have to handle `error` and/or `complete` cases.
If you do have to handle those cases, you have to choose between the 1st or the 2nd way you showed in your question; either one works, just keep consistency in your code (always use the same way in your code; use a linter).

For reference: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe

Comment: can't you handle errors using the 3rd way though? What do you mean `which will be executed on success`? Doesn't the code inside subscribe for the 3rd way only get executed on non-error? Do these 3 ways handle nulls any differently?

Comment: Yes you can, by giving a second closure as a 2nd parameter, but it is deprecated (see reference link). I meant "will be executed when receiving a value that is not an error (which would be handled in the `error`closure)". All `next` closures will only be executed on non errors; errors are handled by the `error` closure. Take a look at the [`Observer` guide](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observer).

Comment: So specifying "next" does basically nothing since by not including the word "next" it behaves the same way as if it wasn't present? I say this because the 3rd way will also not run the code inside {} if the API fails/observable error. The error can be "caught" / handled using `}, error => { <stuffToDoOnError> })` Why does it exist if it does the same thing as just not including it?

Comment: `Observable.subscribe(<closure>)` is just a shortcut to `Observable.subscribe({ next: <closure> })`, there is not much more to say. If you want to handle errors, you need to use `Observable.subscribe({ next: <closure-success>, error: <closure-error> })`. As for "why",  [here is the devs explanation](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments).

Comment: I read the "explanation" and it just told me there are even more confusing ways to use .subscribe vs the cleaner 3rd way. They're considering adding MORE ways to obfuscate .subscribe(). Why couldn't they have just gotten this right the first time, or instead of deprecating old/unsupported syntax, just remove it entirely? Why would they continue to hold onto these pointless barriers that increase the amount of time needed to pick up on new things, reduce productivity, cause confusion, etc.? If you don't need "next" why have it there, especially when "next" is a common term used with Subject?

Comment: No, there is only 2 main ways. With a `PartialObserver`, or just the `next` closure shortcut; nothing complex about it. They didn't get rid of it right away for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three method of Observable conceptually as below:

1. next(): this method define that how to process data which is sent by observable
2. error(): this method define that how to manage error handling activities.
3. complete(): this method define course of action need to perform after the observable has completed producing and emitting data.
4. next() method cannot be executed after the observable has errored or completed.
5. next(), error() or complete() method cannot be called after unsubscribe.
6. unsubscribe is called on error or complete to free the resources used by the subscription and the observable.

### Exmaple

```
some$.subscribe({  
  next: x => console.log('The next value is: ', x),  
  error: err => console.error('An error occurred :', err),  
  complete: () => console.log('There are no more action happen.')  
});
```

So, Final and summary answer of your question is `next` get the latest value from the stream of `Observable`.

Comment: Does that `complete` unsubscribe the observable automatically ? or we still need to unsubscribed manually.

Comment: still you need to unsubscribe.